# How to catch 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' in a comprehensive list

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape urls from a website. I am using beautifulsoup4.

The structure I am trying to scrape is like this:
[HTML Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWIQ9.png)

The code I am using is this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
all_urls = [x.p.a.get('href') for x in soup.findAll("div", class_="b-accordion__text")]
```

When I run the script I receive the following error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

This is probably due to the fact that some of the divs are empty and contain no p/a and therefor the get  function is called on a none existing object.

```
 <div class="b-accordion__text">
</div>
```

When I try to add an if expression like:

```
all_urls = [x.p.a.get('href') for x in soup.findAll("div", class_="b-accordion__text") if x.p.a]
```

I then receive the error that a not exists:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Due to the fact that I am super new to Python I do not know how to handle this error. I would have expected a warning that some of the elements did not have a p/a and the script would still run through. But it aborts.

Question: How to handle/catch that error for div tags that are empty?

Comment: `all_urls = [x.p.a.get('href') for x in soup.findAll("div", class_="b-accordion__text") if x.p.a]`. While I am not too new to python, this should help i.e. `if x.p.a`

Comment: @shahkalpesh Unfortunately not working. I have added this to the original post.

Comment: Oops, it should have been `if x.p`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a double if statement in the comprehensive list to check wether it has a "p" and a "a" attribute solved the issue:

```
all_urls = [x.p.a.get('href') for x in soup.findAll("div", class_="b-accordion__text") if x.p and x.p.a]
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the code but you can add a condition in your list comprehension as follows:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
all_urls = [x.p.a.get('href') for x in soup.findAll("div", class_="b-accordion__text") if not x.p.a is None]
```

More generally, to test for a specific attribute, you can use the *hasattr* built-in function.

Comment: Same as the comment from @shahkalpesh in the original post. Still not working.